# Median of a Matrix with sorted rows

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, binary-search

I am not able to solve the following problem optimally nor finding an approach to do this anywhere.

> Given a N × M matrix in which each row is sorted, find the overall median of the matrix. Assume N*M is odd.
>
> For example,
>
> Matrix =
>   [1, 3, 5]
>   [2, 6, 9]
>   [3, 6, 9]
>
> A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 9, 9]
>
> Median is 5. So, we return 5.
>   Note: No extra memory is allowed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: start with a row and add rows one by one, computing median of the current submatrix every time.

Comment: `No extra memory is allowed` make that _only constant extra memory is allowed_.

Comment: @greybeard does quickselect run in O(1) memory? I don't think so.

Comment: Nevermind, my idea didn't work in the end.

Comment: `Nevermind, my idea didn't work in the end.` same here (but for the first step ending up in a comment to [sunkuet02's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41414832/3789665)). O(1) extra space is _mean_.

Comment: (Here's a bright idea [how to find the median/ _k_ th element in N sorted sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6182649/3789665) with O(N) extra space.)

Comment: Please explicitly state the domain of the matrix elements and whether modification of the matrix is admissible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the following process.

- If we consider the N*M matrix as 1-D array then the median is the element of `1+N*M/2` th element.
- Then consider x will be the median if x is an element of the matrix and number of matrix elements ≤ x equals `1 + N*M/2`.
- As the matrix elements in each row are sorted then you can easily find the number of elements in each row `less than or equals x`. For finding in the whole matrix, the complexity is `N*log M` with binary search.
- Then first find the minimum and maximum element from the N*M matrix. Apply Binary Search on that range and run the above function for each x.
- If the number of elements in matrix `≤ x` is `1 + N*M/2` and x contains in that matrix then `x` is the median.

You can consider this below C++ Code :

```cpp
int median(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
    int min = A[0][0], max = A[0][0];
    int n = A.size(), m = A[0].size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (A[i][0] < min) min = A[i][0];
        if (A[i][m-1] > max) max = A[i][m-1];
    }

    int element = (n * m + 1) / 2;
    while (min < max) {
        int mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cnt += upper_bound(&A[i][0], &A[i][m], mid) - &A[i][0];
        if (cnt < element)
            min = mid + 1;
        else
            max = mid;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: This is an OK algorithm but it's `O(log max(A[i][j]))` i.e. complexity depends on values stored in the matrix. What if the values are huge?

Comment: I think you can replace the comment with `(upper_bound(&A[i][0], &A[i][m], mid) - &A[i][0];)`

Comment: if huge is 10^18 then it needs at most 64 iteration.

Comment: The matrix could store things that are not numbers but some black box data type you can compare but cannot do arithmetic on.

Comment: @n.m. I thought it simple and gives a solution. I think hatellla wants a solution for integer number.

Comment: Instead of using the global minimum and maximum of the matrix elements, you can use the middle element/median of each row: More than half of the elements will be no smaller than their min, more than half no greater than their max (doesn't _necessarily_ reduce the range, but needs only about half the comparisons - pity you can't use `std::minmax()`.

Comment: Isn't number of matrix elements ≤ x equals just N*M/2 and not 1+ N*M/2?

Comment: @sunkuet02 Two doubts. 1) Why is it `max = mid` and not `max = mid-1` 2) Why are we returning `min`?

Comment: mid just seems like a number calculated from (min, max). How are we making sure that mid is actually a number inside the matrix?

Comment: What is `upper_bound()`?

Comment: @dk123 this is because lower value that max could achieve is the median ans value. After max achieves this lowermost value, min will get incremented till it becomes equal to ans value. Consider 1*3 matrix [1 10 100] - Iter1 min 1 max 50, Iter2 min 1 max 25, Iter3 min 1 max 13, Iter4 min 8 max 13, Iter5 min 8 max 10---now max freezes and iteration continues , Iter6 min 10 max 10 break ans =10

Comment: @MokholiaPokholia it can be made to work, but the running time quoted was for one iteration, with log(n) iterations required, missing your desired running time by a log factor.

Answer (score 4):

This Question is quite similar to finding kth smallest element in a row and column wise sorted matrix.

So this problem can be solved using binary search and optimised counting in a sorted Matrix. A binary search takes O(log(n)) time and for each search value it takes n iterations on average to find the numbers that are smaller than the searched number. The search space for binary search is limited to the minimum value in the Matrix at mat[0][0] and the maximum value mat[n-1][n-1].

For every number that is chosen from the binary search we need to count the numbers that are smaller than or equal to that particular number. And thus the k^th smallest number or the median can be found.

For better understanding you can refer to this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5wLN4UweAM&t=145s

Comment: If our example was : 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 and while doing binary search, our mid came out to be '2'. So if we find count of numbers less than or equal to '2', we get 8 , but since it's the median , weren't we expecting it's count to be (n*m+1)/2 ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple O(1) memory solution is to check if each individual element *z* is the median. To do this we find the position of *z* in all rows, just accumulating the number of elements smaller than *z*. This doesn't use the fact that each row is sorted except finding the position of *z* in each row in *O(log M)* time. For each element we need to do *N*log M* comparisons, and there are *N*M* elements, so it is *N²M log M*.

Comment: This can be improved by ignoring elements smaller than the current maximum value known to yield too few lower elements as well as symmetrically those greater than the current minimum known to yield too many. (Doesn't change _worst case_ complexity - expected case should be _Θ(logNM)_ elements to check with _Ο(NlogM)_ complexity - about _Ο(Nlog²NlogM)_? Err - would that be _Ο(NM)_?!)

Comment: @greybeard, actually I didn't think about optimisation of the simple naive algorithm. I saw the OPs Q does not have any valid answer, so I wrote this. You are right, with randomisation we can quickly improve the running time. I guess we can improve it without randomisation as well. If OP explicitly state that he wants an optimum algorithm then I may think about it. But right now I think the main point was O (1) memory nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix elements are integers, one can binary search the median starting with the matrix range for hi and low. O(n log m log(hi-low)).

Otherwise, one way that has O(n²log²m) wost-case time complexity is to binary search, O(log m), for each row in turn, O(n), the closest element to the overall matrix median from the left and the closest from the right, O(n log m), updating the best so far. We know the overall median has no more than `floor(m * n / 2)` elements strictly less than it, and that adding the number of elements less than it and the number of times it occurs can be no less than `floor(m * n / 2) + 1`. We use standard binary search on the row, and – as greybeard pointed out – skip the test for elements outside our 'best' range. The test for how close an element is to the overall median involves counting how many elements in each row are strictly less than it and how many equal, which is achieved in `O(n log m)` time with `n` binary searches. Since the row is sorted, we know greater elements would be more "to the right" and lesser elements more "to the left" in relation to the overall median.

If one is permitted to rearrange the matrix, O(mn log (mn)) time complexity is possible by sorting the matrix in place (using block sort, for example) and returning the middle element.

Comment: @greybeard Sure, thank you for commenting. Each row will have one element that's closest to the overall median from the left and one from the right (or be missing one of those). Since each row is sorted, we can use binary search. Testing how close an element is to the median requires O(n log m) comparisons, and we'd need O(n * log m) such tests. Not sure what you meant about an expectation, nor where you thought I intended to prevent a line break (editing/format looks fine to me).

Comment: @greybeard I added more detail in the answer. Please let me know if I could further clarify.

Comment: `Please let me know if I could further clarify.` It took me _some_ time to see an idea in your description - I'm not sure it is the one you intended. _WLOG, start with the median of the first row and establish the counts of matrix elements lower than(, equal to) and greater than it (binary search in each row but the one of the_ median candidate _). If #lower < #greater, the median may still be in the first row, but to the left (symmetrical cases too long for a comment): do a binary search for the best candidate in the first row. Keeping the candidate up to date, continue through rows 2 to N._

Comment: You could keep _two_ values instead of _best candidate known_: _best above_ and _best below_. You never need to evaluate a candidate outside this range.

Comment: @greybeard thank you for your comments. I couldn't completely follow the longer one above but I think it matches my idea - binary search each row for the best; and, yes, I meant update both the closest from left and the closest from the right.

Comment: `I couldn't completely follow [your longer comment] above` After trying to put it in words of my own, the difference seems to be in _explicitly_ stating there is an "outer" binary search picking and evaluating _candidates_ in each row, with each _evaluation_ using binary searches to establish #below & #above.

Comment: (Created a mess implementing this with "early-outs" everywhere.)

Comment: @greybeard tx for the great suggestion of skipping elements outside the best range.

Comment: גלעד-ברקן@גלעדברקן Like greybreard, I'm having trouble quite following which elements get searched at what time. I think it would really help me if you added some pseudocode.

Comment: @jbapple thank you for your comment. Let's go step by step: (1) a test for whether a particular element is the median can be done in `O(n log m)` time with `n` binary searches summing how many elements in each row are lower than and how many equal to the element. Clear so far?

Comment: `/* Got it so far */
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, typename M>
bool MedianCheck(T x, M& m) {
  int bef = 0, aft = 0;
  for (auto& v : m) {
    auto r = std::equal_range(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
    bef += r.first - v.begin();
    aft += v.end() - r.second;
  }
  auto s = (m.size() * m[0].size()) / 2;
  return bef <= s && aft <= s;
};
`

Comment: @jbapple ok. Step (2) on the first matrix row, use binary search to find the closest element to the median from the left and the closest from the right (there may be only one of those). Step (1) provides the test for how close it is from either side (i.e., how many elements smaller it is short or how many it has extra). (Also, at any point, elements outside the best range so far need not be tested.) How about step 2?

Comment: I think I have it now. I plan to edit your post to add code. I may not get to it until tomorrow.

Comment: @jbapple Awesome! (But perhaps you could add another answer with your code? I would prefer to leave this one just worded.)

Comment: OK, I added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a randomized algorithm that solves this problem in O(n (log n) (log m)) time. It is a [Las Vegas algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm), which means it always give correct results but might take longer than expected. In this case, the probability that it takes much longer than expected is extremely small.

When m = 1, this problem reduces to the problem of finding the median in a read-only array using constant space. That problem does not have a known optimal solution: see ["Finding median in read-only memory on integer input, Chan et al."](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmchan/select_isaac.pdf)

One odd thing about this reduction of the problem when m = 1 is that this **sub**case is also a **super**case, in that an algorithm for m = 1 can be applied to the m > 1 case. The idea is to just forget that the array rows are sorted and treat the entire storage area as an unsorted array of size n * m. So, for instance, the trivial algorithm for the m = 1 case, in which each element is checked to see if it is the median, takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. Applying it when m > 1 takes O(n<sup>2</sup>m<sup>2</sup>) time.

Going back to the m = 1 case, in the comparison model (in which the items of the array can be integers, strings, real numbers, or anything else that can be compared with the inequality operators "<", ">"), the best known deterministic solution that uses space *s* (where *s* is a constant, i.e. in O(1)) has time ϴ(2<sup>s</sup>s!n<sup>1 + 1/s</sup>), and it is more complex than the usual algorithms discussed on stackoverflow (though not on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com or https://cs.stackexchange.com). It uses a chained sequence of algorithms A<sub>s</sub>, A<sub>s-1</sub>, ..., A<sub>1</sub>, where A<sub>s+1</sub> calls A<sub>s</sub>. You can read it in ["Selection from read-only memory and sorting with minimum data movement", by Munro and Raman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(95)00225-1).

There is a simple randomized algorithm with a smaller run time with high probability. For any constant c, this algorithm runs in time O(n log n) with probability 1 - O(n<sup>-c</sup>). When the array is the matrix of size n*m that works out to O(n m log (n m)).

This algorithm is very much like quickselect without the rearranging of elements during partitioning.

```python
import random

def index_range(needle, haystack):
  """The index range' of a value over an array is a pair
  consisting of the number of elements in the array less
  than that value and the number of elements in the array
  less than or equal to the value.
  """
  less = same = 0
  for x in haystack:
    if x < needle: less += 1
    elif x == needle: same += 1
  return less, less + same

def median(xs):
  """Finds the median of xs using O(1) extra space. Does not
  alter xs.
  """
  if not xs: return None
  # First, find the minimum and maximum of the array and
  # their index ranges:
  lo, hi = min(xs), max(xs)
  lo_begin, lo_end = index_range(lo, xs)
  hi_begin, hi_end = index_range(hi, xs)
  # Gradually we will move the lo and hi index ranges closer
  # to the median.
  mid_idx = len(xs)//2
  while True:
    print "range size", hi_begin - lo_end
    if lo_begin <= mid_idx < lo_end:
      return lo
    if hi_begin <= mid_idx < hi_end:
      return hi
    assert hi_begin - lo_end > 0
    # Loop over the array, inspecting each item between lo
    # and hi. This loops sole purpose is to reservoir sample
    # from that set. This makes res a randomly selected
    # element from among those strictly between lo and hi in
    # xs:
    res_size = 0
    res = None
    for x in xs:
      if lo < x < hi:
        res_size += 1
        if 1 == random.randint(1, res_size):
          res = x
    assert res is not None
    assert hi_begin - lo_end == res_size
    # Now find which size of the median res is on and
    # continue the search on the smaller region:
    res_begin, res_end = index_range(res, xs)
    if res_end > mid_idx:
      hi, hi_begin, hi_end = res, res_begin, res_end
    else:
      lo, lo_begin, lo_end = res, res_begin, res_end
```

It works by maintaining upper and lower bounds on the value of the median. It then loops over the array and randomly selects a value between the bounds. That value replaces one of the bounds and the process starts again.

The bounds are accompanied by their index range, a measure of which indexes the bound would appear at if the array were sorted. Once one of the bounds would appear at the index ⌊n/2⌋, it is the median and the algorithm terminates.

When an element is randomly selected in the gap between the bounds, this reduces the gap by 50% in expectation. The algorithm terminates (at the latest) when the gap is 0. We can model this as a series of random independent uniformly distributed variables X<sub>i</sub> from (0,1) such that Y<sub>k</sub> = X<sub>1</sub> * X<sub>2</sub> * ... * X<sub>k</sub> where X<sub>i</sub> is the ratio of the gap that remains after round i. For instance, if after the 10th round the gap between the index ranges of `lo` and `hi` is 120, and after the 11th round the gap is 90, then X<sub>11</sub> = 0.75. The algorithm terminates when Y<sub>k</sub> < 1/n, because the gap is then less than 1.

Pick a constant positive integer k. Let's bound the probability that Y<sub>k log<sub>2</sub>n</sub> >= 1/n using Chernoff bounds. We have Y<sub>k log<sub>2</sub>n</sub> = X<sub>1</sub> * X<sub>2</sub> * ... X<sub>k log<sub>2</sub>n</sub>, so ln Y<sub>k log<sub>2</sub>n</sub> = ln X<sub>1</sub> + ln X<sub>2</sub> + ... + ln X<sub>k log<sub>2</sub>n</sub>. The Chernoff bound then gives Pr(ln X<sub>1</sub> + ln X<sub>2</sub> + ... + ln X<sub>k log<sub>2</sub>n</sub> >= ln (1/n)) <= min<sub>t > 0</sub> e<sup>-t ln (1/n)</sup> (E[e<sup>t ln X<sub>1</sub></sup>] * E[e<sup>t ln X<sub>2</sub></sup>] * ... * E[e<sup>t ln X<sub>k log<sub>2</sub> n</sub></sup>]). After some simplification, the right-hand side is min<sub>t > 0</sub> n<sup>t</sup> (E[X<sub>1</sub><sup>t</sup>] * E[X<sub>2</sub><sup>t</sup>] * ... * E[X<sub>k log<sub>2</sub> n</sub><sup>t</sup>]). Since this is a minimum and we are looking for an upper bound, we can weaken this by specializing to t = 1. It then simplifies to n<sup>1-k</sup>, since E[X<sub>i</sub>] = 1/2.

If we pick, for instance, k = 6, then this bounds the probability that there are 6 log<sub>2</sub>n rounds or more by n<sup>-5</sup>. So with probability 1 - O(n<sup>-5</sup>) the algorithm performs 6 log<sub>2</sub>n - 1 or fewer rounds. This is what I mean by "with high probability" above.

Since each round inspects every member of the array a constant number of times, each round takes linear time, for a total running time of O(n log n) with high probability. When the array is not just an array but a matrix of size n * m that works out to O(n m log (n m)).

We can do substantially better, however, by taking advantage of the sortedness of the rows. When we were working in a single unsorted array, finding the elements in the gap I referenced above required inspecting each element of the array. In a matrix with sorted rows, the elements in the gap are located in a contiguous segment of each row. Each segment can be identified in O(log m) time using binary search, so they can all be located in O(n log m) time. The reservoir sampling now takes O(n log m) time per iteration of the loop.

The other main work done in the loop is to identify the index range of the element from the gap that was randomly selected. Again, because each row is sorted, the index range for the randomly-chosen element in a row can be determined in O(log m) time. The sums of the index ranges for each row constitute the index range over the whole array, so this part of each loop iteration also takes only O(n log m) time.

By the same argument as above with the Chernoff bound, there are O(log n) iterations with probability at least 1-O(n<sup>-k</sup>) for any constant k. Thus the whole algorithm takes O(n (log n) (log m)) time with high probability.

```python
import bisect
import random

def matrix_index_range(needle, haystack):
  """matrix_index_range calculates the index range of needle
  in a haystack that is a matrix (stored in row-major order)
  in which each row is sorted"""
  n, m = len(haystack), len(haystack[0])
  begin = end = 0;
  for x in haystack:
    begin += bisect.bisect_left(x, needle)
    end += bisect.bisect_right(x, needle)
  return begin, end

def matrix_median(xs):
  print "Starting"
  if not xs or not xs[0]: return None
  n, m = len(xs), len(xs[0])
  lo, hi = xs[0][0], xs[0][m-1]
  for x in xs:
    lo, hi = min(lo, x[0]), max(hi, x[m-1])
  lo_begin, lo_end = matrix_index_range(lo, xs)
  hi_begin, hi_end = matrix_index_range(hi, xs)
  mid_idx = (n * m) // 2
  while True:
    print "range size", hi_begin - lo_end
    if lo_begin <= mid_idx < lo_end:
      return lo
    if hi_begin <= mid_idx < hi_end:
      return hi
    assert hi_begin - lo_end > 0
    mid = None
    midth = random.randint(0, hi_begin - lo_end - 1)
    for x in xs:
      gap_begin = bisect.bisect_right(x, lo)
      gap_end = bisect.bisect_left(x, hi)
      gap_size = gap_end - gap_begin
      if midth < gap_size:
        mid = x[gap_begin + midth]
        break
      midth -= gap_size
    assert mid is not None
    mid_begin, mid_end = matrix_index_range(mid, xs)
    assert lo_end <= mid_begin and mid_end <= hi_begin
    if mid_end > mid_idx:
      hi, hi_begin, hi_end = mid, mid_begin, mid_end
    else:
      lo, lo_begin, lo_end = mid, mid_begin, mid_end
```

This solution is substantially faster than the first one when m is non-constant.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded the O(n<sup>2</sup> log<sup>2</sup> m) time solution of גלעד ברקן, but they have asked me to not add the code to their answer, so here it is as a separate answer:

```python
import bisect

def MedianDistance(key, matrix):
  lo = hi = 0
  for row in matrix:
    lo += bisect.bisect_left(row, key)
    hi += bisect.bisect_right(row, key)
  mid = len(matrix) * len(matrix[0]) // 2;
  if hi - 1 < mid: return hi - 1 - mid
  if lo > mid: return lo - mid
  return 0

def ZeroInSorted(row, measure):
  lo, hi = -1, len(row)
  while hi - lo > 1:
    mid = (lo + hi) // 2
    ans = measure(row[mid])
    if ans < 0: lo = mid
    elif ans == 0: return mid
    else: hi = mid

def MatrixMedian(matrix):
  measure = lambda x: MedianDistance(x, matrix)
  for idx, row in enumerate(matrix):
    if not idx & idx-1: print(idx)
    ans = ZeroInSorted(row, measure)
    if ans is not None: return row[ans]
```

Comment: In `MedianDistance()`, you can use `l = bisect.bisect_left(row, key) lo += l hi += bisect.bisect_right(row, key, l)`. As of rev. 1, `ZeroInSorted()` doesn't make use of known lower and upper bounds for the median - too lazy to check correspondence to complexity claims.

Answer (score 1):

Using Las Vegas Algorithm:

```
from random import randint

def findMedian(matrix):
    #getting the length of columns and rows
     N = len(matrix)
     M = len(matrix[0])
     while True:
           counter = 0
           #select a row randomly
           u = randint(0,len(matrix)-1)
           #select a column randomly
           v = randint(0,len(matrix[0])-1)
           #random index
           x = matrix[u][v]
          for i in range(len(matrix)):
             for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
                 if matrix[i][j] < x:
                        counter+=1
          #finding median
          if counter == (N*M-1)//2:
     return (x)



 arr = [[1,3,5],
        [2,6,9],
        [3,6,9]]

 findMedian(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

[sunkuet02's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41414832/3789665) with refinements and python code:
Each row of the N×M matrix `A` is sorted and has a middle element, which is its median.
There are at least N*(M+1)/2 elements no larger than the maximum *hi* of these medians, and at least N*(M+1)/2 no smaller than the minimum *lo*:
the median of all elements of `A` must be between *lo* and *hi*, inclusive.
As soon as more than half the elements are known to be lower than the current candidate, the latter is known to be high. As soon as there are too few rows remaining for the count of elements lower than the current candidate to reach half the total, the candidate is known to be low: in both cases, immediately proceed to the next candidate.

```python
from bisect import bisect

def median(A):
    """ returns the median of all elements in A.
        Each row of A needs to be in ascending order. """
    # overall median is between min and max row median
    lo, hi = minimax(A)
    n = len(A)
    middle_row = n // 2
    columns = len(A[0])
    half = (n * columns + 1) // 2
    while lo < hi:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        lower = 0
        # first half can't decide median
        for a in A[:middle_row]:
            lower += bisect(a, mid)
        # break as soon as mid is known to be too high or low
        for r, a in enumerate(A[middle_row:n-1]):
            lower += bisect(a, mid)
            if half <= lower:
                hi = mid
                break
            if lower < r*columns:
                lo = mid + 1
                break
        else: # decision in last row
            lower += bisect(A[n-1], mid)
            if half <= lower:
                hi = mid
            else:
                lo = mid + 1

    return lo


def minmax(x, y):
    """return min(x, y), max(x, y)"""
    if x < y:
        return x, y
    return y, x


def minimax(A):
    """ return min(A[0..m][n//2]), max(A[0..m][n//2]):
        minimum and maximum of medians if A is a
        row major matrix with sorted rows."""
    n = len(A)
    half = n // 2
    if n % 2:
        lo = hi = A[0][half]
    else:
        lo, hi = minmax(A[0][half], A[1][half])
    for i in range(2-n % 2, len(A[0]), 2):
        l, h = minmax(A[i][half], A[i+1][half])
        if l < lo:
            lo = l
        if hi< h:
            hi = h
    return lo, hi


if __name__ =='__main__':
    print(median( [[1, 3, 5], [2, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]] ))
```

(I consider `std::upper_bound()` and `bisect.bisect()` to be equivalent (`bisect_right()` is an alias).)
For the second *candidate median*, the last row processed may be lower than in the first iteration. In following iterations, that rownumber should never decrease - too lazy to factor *that* in ((rename and) increase `middle_row` as appropriate).

Comment: Actually that answer is not good in general. e.g it doesn't work for real numbers. Or it depends to the size of largest element ....

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Please try to separate general problems from algorithm ones and from implementation problems. The problem statement looks _exercise in a CS course_ or _interview question_ - the answers would be quite different with a space limit of _O(N+M)_ (even _O(N+√M)_). Given an integers-only example , I think sunkuet02 justified to assume integer elements, as well as anyone else _until hatellla declares the question has been misinterpreted_. (The approach in both sunkuet02's and my answer looks a bitch to modify for floating point values _that may even be non unique_ as in the example.)

Comment: We just now each row is sorted. It means that its elements are comparable, nothing more. We don't even know if they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see people are many doubts for @sunkuet02 algorithm. I will try to answer this question. It might be helpful to other people.

Questions asked bu @user248884.

**1) Why is it max = mid and not max = mid-1?**

```
 if (cnt < element)
        min = mid + 1;
    else
        max = mid;
```

Solution can be the mid element. Suppose we have r=1 c=4 and A[][4]={{1,2,9,10}};
Here, min = 1 and max=10. Therefore mid=5 which is the answer. 
Which means you cannot leave the mid element.

**2) Why are we returning min?**
Actually it does not matter. You can return max also, as both will give the same answer.

```
while (min < max) { ...}
```

While loop will break when min == max. So, one can return min or max does not matter. Just think.

Question asked by @Seaky Lone

**3. What is upper_bound()?**
This a function takes 3 argument array start (more precisely iterator begin), last index till you want to check (not including last element) and a **X**.  It will return the first element index which is greater than **X**. By using this function can get the number of elements less than X.

Question asked by @dk123

**4.How are we making sure that mid is actually a number inside the matrix?**

In this algo, we are not checking whether the median exists in the array. 
For doing that, after getting the probable median, check into the matrix for existence. If not, then find the **nearest smallest element** to median